# Fastest way to send large ( 1TB) data files overseas (Azure or OTS solution)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

The requirement is to facilitate the transfer of large (1 TB) files from Europe to the United States as quickly as possible. How would I go about building something in Azure storage/networking? Or please point me to some OTS solutions so I can find out more.

The use case is LiDAR data taken over seas needs to be transmitted back to East and or West coast US as quickly as possible. Sender may or may not be near a data center.

Thanks

Comment: Tool/product recommendation questions are expressly off-topic for StackOverflow. Aside from that, this is a very broad question, with no "right" answer. And physics dictates what "as quickly as possible" can actually be. Have you tried just copying a large blob between regions?

Comment: If you have a data in Azure Storage Account, you can copy/move storage account objects to your other storage account using the AzCopy tool/ Azure PowerShell/ Storage Explorer.

Comment: @Vikranth Thanks for that. I will put it on the list. I also was looking into Azure File Sync but that seems like overkill. I found what i was looking for (I think). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arch, Azure provides several alternatives as well depending on your scenario, it will also depend on how often are you going to transfer the data, is it a one time case scenario or everyday etc...

> AzCopy
>   AzCopy is a Windows command-line utility designed for high-performance copying of data to and from Azure Storage. You can also copy data within a storage account, or between different storage accounts.

**Moving large amounts of data with a slow network**

> One of the biggest challenges associated with moving large amounts of data is the transfer time. If you want to get data to/from Azure Storage without worrying about networks costs or writing code, then Azure Import/Export is an appropriate solution.

Many other alternatives can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-moving-data)

Answer (score 0):

[This is the document to read on sending files over WAN as fast as possible.](http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/HOWTO_move_data.html#_problems_with_moving_data_across_wans)

From that document I discovered IBM Aspera which I will check out. That doc also has lots of great info on this topic though.